# Will compiler unroll "for" loop when iterating a const container?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, we can use a much simpler "for" loop when iterating a container like the following:

```
for (auto i : {1, 2, 3, 4})
    ...;
```

However, I don't know the efficiency of such code. Specifically:

- What is the type of {1, 2, 3, 4}? It is an raw array, or converted to other containers such as std::vector?
- Will compiler unroll the loop?

Update: Suppose we are using -O2, and the codes in the loop are only a few operations.
As my case, I want to enumarate four directions UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT and call a function with the direction parameter. I just care if the program can have the best performance.

Thank you very much!

Comment: *Will compiler unroll the loop?* It depends on what you do in your loop. You can use https://godbolt.org/ to explore what various compilers will do.

Comment: *Will compiler unroll the loop?* depends on what compiler, what the optimization level is, and possibly other factors. I'm not aware of any guarantees on loop unrolling.

Comment: "What is the type of {1, 2, 3, 4}?" it is `std::initializer_list` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: Yep, that's an `initializer_list`. "Will compiler unroll the loop?" **What** compiler? And why can't you just compile it and check?? I'm voting to close as too broad, especially given that there is no info on the compiler and actual code being asked about - and, even if that weren't the case, because it is unlikely to be something that can be answered certainly, just tested empirically.

Comment: About the "Will compiler unroll the loop?" part, if you are using Clang, it has a high chance that the for loop does not exist in compiled code, you can use -S to output an assembly output. Also, as @FrançoisAndrieux motioned, Godbolt is a valuable tool to explore the magic in compilers.

Comment: The compiler will unroll it if it determines it will be beneficial to do so, given the parameters it has been given.

Comment: do you really care if the compiler unrolls the loop? or do you just care about performance of the resulting executable? Those are not the same. Usually compilers are much better in deciding when to apply an optimization and when not

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! I just care if the program can have the best performance. In fact, for may case, I want to enumarate four directions UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT and call a function with the direction parameter.

Comment: If all is constant, there is no need to unroll! The compiler may calculate the complete result so you will see nothing but the result of the expressions!

Comment: @zbh2047: *Measure, optimize, measure.* Don't worry about micro-optimizations like this until you have *determined* that there is a problem in a *specific* piece of code. Most of the time performance is determined by the efficiency of higher-level algorithms, not whether a certain loop is unrolled by the compiler or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the type of {1, 2, 3, 4}?

`std::initializer_list` will be constructed from that initialiser. That is being iterated. You even need to include `<initializer_list>` for this to work.

> Will compiler unroll the loop?

The language doesn't guarantee loop unrolling. You can find out whether a particular compiler unrolls a particular loop with particular options with particular target CPU by compiling and inspecting the produced assembly.

That said, the number of iterations is known at compile time, and therefore it is *possible* for the compiler to unroll the entire loop.

---

> Suppose we are using -O2

For what it's worth, -O2 does not enable -funroll-loops. Before you add that option, read its documentation:

> -funroll-loops
>
> Unroll loops whose number of iterations can be determined at compile time or upon entry to the loop. -funroll-loops implies
> -frerun-cse-after-loop. This option makes code larger, and may or may not make it run faster.

In this example, Clang did unroll the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/enKzMh while GCC did not: https://godbolt.org/z/ocfor8

Answer (score 5):

There is no guarantee, but compilers can optimize certain cases, so chances are high that you end up with good code.

For example, that one can be optimized away completely:

```
#include <initializer_list>

// Type your code here, or load an example.
int sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i : {1, 2, 3, 4}) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
  return sum();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/racnKf

Compiled with `-O3`, gcc can deduce that the result of the compuation is 10:

```
sum():
        mov     eax, 10
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, 10
        ret
```

In a real world example, the compiler might not be able to optimize it, so you have to verify yourself.